# Element with fixed position bumps on scroll only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, css-position

I have a div with fixed position. When I scroll inside a component, I calculate position of another div in order to "stick" the fixed position div to it - so on every scroll position of a fixed element changes. 
In chrome everything works correctly but in firefox I have a situation that after every scroll the fixed div "chases" div to its new position. 
The strange thing is that when I turn on and off developer tools in firefox, problem disapears. 
I don't understand why dev tools helps to workaround this problem and why in chrome it works correctly.

I know that this is a hack and it should be anchored to the div it is 'chasing' but in this case I don't have time to refactor implementation.

Comment: So what is your question? How can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: Make a div with {overflow-y: auto}. Inside that div, set two divs (lets name them a and b). Set the b div to {position: fixed, top: <position of a div + a.hight>}
Now on scroll position of a will change, so should b. In firefox when position is changing it "bumps" to it's new position